# Integrating Elasticsearch with Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

In Java when using Hibernate Search for instance you bind JPA insertion, removal and update events to the search engine so that it automatically insert, updates and removes elements from the search engine index at the same time inserting, updating or removing it from the database. Is the same possible in Ruby and when using active record? Or do you manually have to register observers?

Comment: have you seen gem Tire (https://github.com/karmi/tire)?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three notable gems allowing you to integrate Elasticsearch with ActiveRecord, some (like elasticsearch-rails, flex, retire) shipping with callback hooks for ActiveRecord that will automatically add, update or destroy an elasticsearch record on the appropriate actions.

1. [**elasticsearch-rails**](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails): The new default
2. [**flex**](https://github.com/ddnexus/flex): Really great wiki
3. [**stretcher**](https://github.com/PoseBiz/stretcher): Runner-up, new option

All of them are actively maintained and developed. A still widely used but no longer maintained gem is retire.

1. [**retire**](https://github.com/karmi/tire): Widely used, but no longer supported

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, neither Flex nor Stretcher come with any ActiveModel/ActiveRecord integration. Tire, on the other hand, focuses _mainly_ on painless ActiveModel/ActiveRecord integration.

Comment: Flex now has ActiveModel/ActiveRecord integration, tire was retired, and flex has parent/child support out of the box which is absent completely from (re)tire. Flex is my choice at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Tire*](https://github.com/karmi/tire) Rubygem comes with a robust [ActiveModel/ActiveRecord integration](https://github.com/karmi/tire#activemodel-integration).

The best option to quickly start is to generate an example Rails application:

```
rails new searchapp -m https://raw.github.com/karmi/tire/master/examples/rails-application-template.rb
```

Also, the [*Railscasts* episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) gives a quick overview of the integration. Tire README and integration test suite have all the information.

Comment: Since September 2013 tire gem has been renamed (into retire) and retired. It is also not not considered compatible with ElasticSearch 1.x.